# How to see if all fields are filled in a form with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, or-operator

I have a form with in between the `<template>` tags

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email address</label>
  <input v-model="email" for="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input v-model="name" for="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input v-model="password" type="password" class="form-control" for="password" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Confirm">Confirm Password</label>
  <input v-model="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" for="Confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" required>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
</div>
<button v-on:click="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

I have `v-model` which is updating the `data` in the `script` section in real time.

The `data`:

```
data(){
return{
  email: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  confirmPassword: undefined,
  name: undefined
}
```

},

I expect `undefined` to be updated by `v-model`

On clicking The form's button the `Submit` method is called.

The `Submit` method:

prints empty if input is `empty` and `passed` if the input is not empty (works as expected)

prints `empty` if input is empty and `empty` even if both the inputs are filled (not as expected)

```
methods:{
Submit(){

  console.log(this.email); //prints the data in entered in the form correctly
  console.log(this.name);  //prints the data in entered in the form correctly
  console.log(this.password); //prints the data in entered in the form correctly
  console.log(this.confirmPassword); //prints the data in entered in the form correctly

  if(this.email == undefined){ console.log('Empty')} //prints empty if input is `empty` and `passed` if the input is not empty (works as expected)
  else{console.log('passed')};


  if(this.email || this.name == undefined){console.log('Empty');} //prints `empty` if input is empty and `empty` even if both the inputs are filled (not as expected) 
  else {console.log('Passed');}
  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OR || operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) will return true if at least one of the operands is true.

In your second if statement it checks `this.email` has a truthy value, OR `this.name` is `undefined`, then it will return true. In your scenario, if both the values are filled, then it will simply be true.

You want to use the [AND && operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) to check if both conditions are truthy.

Alternatively, for vue, you can use a validation library like [Vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) or [VeeValidate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/).

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing `if(this.email || this.name == undefined)` to `if(this.email == undefined || this.name == undefined)` Thanks